# target folder is getting created while building pom.xml - maven

Tags: maven, svn

I want to copy the files from Unix/linux server to SVN repository

Do svn export work?
If yes, please help with command how exactly I have to write the command.
 Suppose if files are unix server on path : /appl/project/dev
And svn repository is : svn://scm.it.abc.com:XXXX/REL100

And i want to copy all files from unix path to SVN repository.